# react state cant delete first letter

Tags: reactjs

[image]I have this code that edit data, it works properly when adding text but removing all letters will not remove first letter.

```
export const Edit = (props: any) => {

    const { initial } = usefetchEditUserType(props)

    return (
        <>
            <CreateUpdate
                title="Edit User Type"
                useMutationHooks={useEditRole(props.id)} /** Change this */
                editPermission={true}
                value={initial} -->
                id={props.id}
            />
            <ListAssignUserAccount {...props} />
        </>
        
    );
};

CreateUpdate

const { inputValidation, handleOnChange, handleOnClickSubmit, data } = useMutationHooks;

<CardContent >
    <TextField
       required
       //...omitted code
        onChange={(e: any) => handleOnChange(e)}
        error={inputValidation['input']}
        helperText={inputValidation['input'] ? "Required*" : ""}
        value={ data ? data : value } --> value from Edit component
    />
    </CardContent>


useEditRole

export const useEditRole = (id: number) => {

    const notify = useNotify()
    const [inputValidation, setInputValidation] = useState({input: false, button: true})
    const [data, setData] = useState("")

    const handleOnClickSubmit = async () => {
        await fetchCreateRole(data, "PUT", id).then((res: any) => {
            notify("Successfully Updated!")
        });
    }

    const handleOnChange = (e: any) => {
        if(e.target.value) {
            setData(e.target.value )
            setInputValidation({ input: false, button: false})
        } else {
            setInputValidation({ input: true, button: true})
        }
    }

    return { inputValidation, handleOnChange, handleOnClickSubmit, data, setData }
}
```

console logging seems working but in text field is not getting the changes input status. Im trying way another but then deleting in input field brings back the original or the default value

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to follow, but I imagine it's due to this: `value={ data ? data : value }` If `data` is an empty string you are telling the input to display something else instead.

Comment: can you check handleOnChange => else part include this code also => setData(''), 
may be thats why is not removing the last character

Comment: I did setData(") however upon deleting all the defaultvalue when erased revert back again